# Updating server keystore each time a new client is added

Tags: java, rest, authentication, x509certificate

I have written a RestFul web service running on tomcat server and a jersey **2.x** rest client for interacting with the service.
The client authentication is being carried out by the method of Certificate-Based Mutual Authentication. I have configured CA certificates at server and I have a client certificate in .PEM format which I am feeding to the java client in Base64 encoded format as

```
base64encodedCert = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path/to/cert_for_clientA.base64")));
// ClientBuilder
// Client initialization
Response response = target.request().header("X-AUTH-TOKEN", base64encodedCert).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();
```

The authentication is a custom-token based type i.e.
***header("X-AUTH-TOKEN", base64encodedCert).***

But this authentication was not working (HTTP error 500?). So I imported the
same client certificate into servers truststore.jks using the `keytool -import command` and re-deployed the application and the client was successfully authenticated.
The issue is I have to update my server's truststore.jks each time a new client certificate is issued , which isn't the ideal way of doing it.

So , I was wondering if there is a way to avoid such repetitive updates in server's truststore and doing onetime setup for client certificate authentication.

**This is a project on my organizations workspace , we have our own PKI infra for issuing certificates not sure if that is going to make a difference